# wMemory Warning and application Crash due to poor ViewController handling?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, warnings, viewcontroller

I have a line of `viewControllers` set in line. The idea is to go through a process of questions etc. If i was to use the already set up way of changing view controller (through button - modal), i would have no problem with memory. I have tried it. However i need to change the views programmatically and not with buttons directly. 
When i do this programmatically my memory usage just starts increasing as i go through the views, until eventually i get a Memory Warning and a crash. 
To change the `viewController` i use custom `UIStoryBoardSegue` and also methods in the `viewController` files.
Here is how i do it:

Method in View Controller:

```
-(void)changeViewController 
{
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.timingFunction =[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];


    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"enterInfoSecondViewController"];
    [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window]rootViewController]presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
   // [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    //[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
    //   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

In custom Segue:

```
-(void)perform
{
    UIViewController *srcViewController = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController*destViewController = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;

    [srcViewController.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];



    [srcViewController presentViewController:destViewController animated:NO completion:nil];


}
 ......
```

Somewhere I do it with segue and somewhere with the top method.
What am i doing wrong? i need help please :) Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to trigger the segue programmatically, 
why not use `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` ?